# Why can I not use the interop assembly created by TLBIMP in .NET?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, com, com-interop

I have a .OCX file which i converted it to interop assembly by visual studio 2010 tools (tlbimp).
When I want to add the created DLL to my .NET project, I receive the exception below:

> 'DLLName.DLL', or one of it dependencies, requires a later version of
>   the .NET Framework than the on specified in the project. You can change
>   the .NET Framework target by clicking properties on the project menu
>   and then selecting a new target in the '.NET Framework' drop down box.

Has anybody have ever experience about this?

Comment: Well, what version of .net are you targeting? And what options did you use with tlbimp? Probably it has included some 4.0 "dynamic" stuff or optional args, and you aren't targeting 4.0. Can you be more specific please?

Comment: My project is based on .NET framework 4.0 and tlbimp has not an option to specify .NET framework version.

Comment: is it full framework? Silverlight? Client-profile? Xna? What?

Comment: You could use the version of tlbimp which comes with an older version of the framework...

Comment: it is a windows form project based on .NET 4.

Comment: Are you sure you are targeting full .net and not client profile?

Comment: @Marc, `dynamic` is supported by the client profile IIRC. However, the interop assembly might require part of WCF, as strange as it seems (`ClientBase<T>` maybe?).

Comment: @Frederic indeed my full vs client was to rule out further dependencies. My "dynamic" point was before the OP confirmed this was targeting 4.0

Answer (score 4):

I can repro that, although it isn't easy:

[image]

The only way to get it is to run Tlbimp.exe from the Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt *and* having the Target Framework setting targeting an earlier version of .NET.  Triple-check this setting.  There's something seriously broken in your setup if the setting is selecting .NET 4.

The better mousetrap is to create the interop library with the IDE.  Project + Add Reference, Browse tab and pick the .ocx file there.  When you change the target framework now, the interop library automatically gets re-generated to match the CLR version.  You can double-check all this by running ildasm.exe on the interop library.  Double-click the manifest, it shows you the target CLR version in the first line:

```
// Metadata version: v4.0.30319
.assembly extern mscorlib
{
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
  .ver 4:0:0:0
}
```

Last but not least, you really want to have the interop library's "Embed Interop Types" property set to True so you don't have to ship the interop library.  If you can't find this property back in the Properties window then you have another hint that the target framework setting is not what you think it is.